# Program execution requirement

Tags: windows, winapi, architecture

I implemented an application using Qt(Qt SDK version 4.8.1) compiled under OS 64b (windows 7) using Microsoft Windows SDK for windows7 (7.1.7600.0.30514) (*86).
My question is what is the minimum required from a client machine to support my program ( so it can be executed successfully )

PS: I used some functions from winapi(windows.h,process.h,Shlwapi.h...) and for Qt libs I run my application statically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surest way to find out is test it.  First, do a release build of your app.  Then do a clean install of Windows (on a VM if you can). Without adding anything else to that machine, install your app.  Does it run?  If not, find out what's missing and add it.  Once your app runs, repeat the process with every version of Windows you intend to support.  When done, you should have a list of everything it needs.

A faster approach is to use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/); however, it will only show you dependent DLLs.  It won't catch other resources your app depends on (files, directories, registry keys, etc), nor will it catch DLLs you're loading dynamically.  If you're building 32- and 64-bit versions of your app, make sure you download both versions of Depends.

EDIT: The server at dependencywalker.com seems to be down.  [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256872) is another source for it.

Comment: Ok thank you it is really helpful, dependencywalker it is not available yet, I run a release build of my application under both 64 and 32 bit machines and it works fine, I build it as I said with using Microsoft Windows SDK for windows7 (7.1.7600.0.30514) (*86) is that mean that is a 32 bit version?(32 and 64 version depends on the builder or the machine?) sorry but I am really confused and I will be grateful if you make it clearer.

Comment: 32- or 64-bit versions of your app depends on the build, not the machine you run it on.  If your app doesn't include device drivers, you can probably build only a 32-bit version since that will run on both 32- and 64-bit machines.

Comment: I added another link to my answer where you can download Dependency Walker.

Comment: thank you @Carey I appreciate your help and your time and sorry for the late,I tried Dependency Walker and it shows me as you said a list of .DLL (winn_core,win_security,kernel32 ...),I even run it under windows xp but it demanded other libs(MSVCP100.DLL and MSVCR100.DLL) probably linked to my builder msvc_2010, so have I build 2 version 32 and 64 bits to avoid any future issue or my 32 bits version is enough even for later versions of windows?

Comment: The 32-bit version is probably sufficient.  Windows will support 32 bits for a long time to come.